# Load a 6 MB binary file in a SQL Server 2005 VARBINARY(MAX) column using ADO/VC++?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-c++, ado

How to load a binary file(.bin) of size 6 MB in a varbinary(MAX) column of SQL Server 2005 database  using ADO in a VC++ application.

This is the code I am using to load the file which I used to load a .bmp file:

```
BOOL CSaveView::PutECGInDB(CString strFilePath, FieldPtr pFileData)
{

 //Open File
 CFile       fileImage;
 CFileStatus fileStatus;
 fileImage.Open(strFilePath,CFile::modeRead);
 fileImage.GetStatus(fileStatus);

 //Alocating memory for data
 ULONG nBytes    = (ULONG)fileStatus.m_size;
 HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GPTR,nBytes);
 LPVOID lpData   = GlobalLock(hGlobal);

 //Putting data into file
 fileImage.Read(lpData,nBytes);

 HRESULT hr;
 _variant_t varChunk;
 long lngOffset     = 0;
 UCHAR chData;
 SAFEARRAY FAR *psa = NULL;
 SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];

 try
 {
  //Create a safe array to store the BYTES
  rgsabound[0].lLbound   = 0;
  rgsabound[0].cElements = nBytes;
  psa                    = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1,1,rgsabound);
  while(lngOffset<(long)nBytes)
  {
   chData = ((UCHAR*)lpData)[lngOffset];
   hr     = SafeArrayPutElement(psa,&lngOffset,&chData);
   if(hr != S_OK)
   {
    return false;
   }
   lngOffset++;
  }
  lngOffset = 0;
  //Assign the safe array to a varient
  varChunk.vt     = VT_ARRAY|VT_UI1;
  varChunk.parray = psa;

  hr = pFileData->AppendChunk(varChunk);
  if(hr != S_OK)
  {
   return false;
  }

 }
 catch(_com_error &e)
 {
      //get info from _com_error
  _bstr_t bstrSource(e.Source());
  _bstr_t bstrDescription(e.Description());
  _bstr_t bstrErrorMessage(e.ErrorMessage());
  _bstr_t bstrErrorCode(e.Error());
  TRACE("Exception thrown for classes generated by #import");
  TRACE("\tCode= %08lx\n",(LPCSTR)bstrErrorCode);
  TRACE("\tCode Meaning = %s\n",(LPCSTR)bstrErrorMessage);
  TRACE("\tSource = %s\n",(LPCSTR)bstrSource);
  TRACE("\tDescription = %s\n",(LPCSTR)bstrDescription);
 }
 catch(...)
 {
  TRACE("***Unhandle Exception***");
 }
 //Free Memory
 GlobalUnlock(lpData);
 return true;
}
```

But when I read the same file using Getchunk function it gives me all 0s but the size of the file I get is same as the one uploaded.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the solution as I am stuck and cannot move further if I am not able to read the .bin file from the database

Comment: I want to load and retrievea .bin file content in a sql server 2005 database varbinary(max) column in a vc++ dialog based application.I am using ADO to connect to the database .Please help me in finding a solution.